# window.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl in ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I need to save a downloaded file in my ionic 2 path and use that ineteral url path.
for downloading: using file-transfer plugin.

```
const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
fileTransfer.download(trackObj.remoteUrl,cordova.file.dataDirectory+"audio/"+filename).then((entry)=>{
    console.log("download completed:"+entry.toURL());
});
```

entry.toURL() is giving path like file://...... in need to use that path to play using Media plugin. But, Media plugin is not accepting path with file://...,

```
this.playerStatic = new MediaPlugin(internalFilePath,onStatusPlayerUpdate);
```

so, on googling foundout: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-9-cant-play-audio-video-files-that-are-downloaded-to-device/37580/4

so using "cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/" + fileSrc; as a temporary solution. Its not working for android.

so to be able to use in both platforms, i should be able to follow other solution, where the path will be resolved to InternalURL. when i try

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(src, function(dir){});
```

its saying resolveLocalFileSystemURL is not a function. 
anybody can help me with it? how to use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL in ionic 2?

Comment: Just remove file:// from that path.

Comment: I am curious but wouldn't giving the remoteUrl to the mediaplugin just work?

Comment: mediaplugin will work, but i want to download and use it for later

Comment: tried removing file://. no luck. getting: ERROR: Unhandled Promise rejection: [object Object] ; Zone: <root> ; Task:  ; Value: [object Object]. so tried getting cdvfile:// url by hardcoding the path for iOS. but can someone suggest the better way?

Comment: I think there's a toInternalURL() method on the File

Answer (score 1):

I am using it in ionic 3, for iOS build. Please check the code:

```
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.file.dataDirectory).then((entry) => {
    console.log("Success! Got a DirectoryEntry",entry);  
});
```

Here, I am using cordova-plugin-file but I think it should work for cordova-plugin-file-transfer also. Please try and let me know, if there is any issue.